# Can my testing error be lower than validation error but higher than training error?

Tags: performance, testing, neural-network, regression, mlp

I am trying a multilayer perceptron with 5 hidden nodes. However the testing error is lower than the validation error and higher than the training error. The coefficient of correlation on the test set is also higher than that on the validation set. Is that acceptable? I've included the regression and performance plots. The generalization is okay according to me; not the best but adequate.

[image]

[image]

This is an ANN-GARCH-type model for volatility.

Comment: You're probably better off asking https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It's hard to tell whether there's an issue here from the little you've given, but  fundamentally any differences should have to be noise since there is no fundamental difference between validation and test prior to training ending.

Comment: Thanks. It's an ANN-GARCH-type model for volatility. By what you see, it's that the network process is adequate then? Because from what I've managed to gather from other studies, the testing error is usually higher than the validation and the validation higher than training error. I've also got another problem....should my test sample correspond to the amount I'm forecasting. Because my forecast amounts to around 5% of my total sample, both insample and outsample. Thus I used 80% for training, 15% validation and 5% testing.